# How to properly call GetGattServicesForUuidAsync?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm having a hard time getting GATT service from my device. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, creating a C++/WinRT console app.  So far I have this code:

```
struct Console 
{
   /* Create a watcher */
   BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

     void Initialize()
    {
        watcher.ScanningMode(BluetoothLEScanningMode::Active);
        watcher.Received({ this, &Console::OnAdvertisementReceived });
        watcher.Start();
    }

    void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher const& _watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs const& args)
    {
        hstring bleDeviceName = L"xxx";
        BluetoothLEAdvertisement adv = args.Advertisement();

        if (adv.LocalName() == bleDeviceName) {
            _watcher.Stop();

            winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation device = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress());

            if (device != NULL) {
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation servicesIncluded = BluetoothLEDevice::GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(MyService_GUID);
            }
        }

        else cout << "No device found " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Console test;
    test.Initialize();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't get this function to work:

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation servicesIncluded = BluetoothLEDevice::GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(MyService_GUID);
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.getgattservicesforuuidasync#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothLEDevice_GetGattServicesForUuidAsync_System_Guid_) the prototype. This is not a static function, and this might have something to do here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should read [C++ - Effective Async with Coroutines and C++/WinRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt846728) for a short introduction, as well as [Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency). Also note, that you are failing to initialize the Windows Runtime.

Comment: First, you must wait when async operation completed when creating your device (FromBluetoothAddressAsync()). Second. You must call GetServices from device object created on previous call, not from class (it is not a class function). May be better to use third party libs to do that?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, thank you. By calling it from device object, do you mean like this:
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation servicesIncluded = device.BluetoothLEDevice::GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(MyService_GUID);

? Which third party libs? Thank you.

Comment: Its really long story to explain it in few words in comment. FromBluetoothAddressAsync() returns something known as IAsyncOperation interface, Not Device (IBluetoothLEDevice) object. When the asynchronous operation of the device cretion completed (you have to wait for it) you must get its result. IN WRT declared few typed interfaces. For the device object the function actually returns IBluetoothLEDeviceAsyncOperation interface. Once it is completed you call GetResults() method which returns IBluetoothLEDevice object. And then you have to call GetGattServicesForUuidAsync from that object.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko: Turning the asynchronous call into a blocking call is just one of your options. You could also `co_await` on the `IAsyncOperation` class template, thereby turning the delegate into a coroutine. All of that is explained in the links I posted in my first comment.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I use co_await like this:  winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation device = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress());  but it gives me many compiler error (not a member of, mo matching overloaded function found, etc.).

Comment: You should read the links. You won't understand any of this, if you are missing the basics of the asynchronous pattern, which is used throughout the Windows Runtime. Anyway, you'd probably want to use `auto const device{ co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress()) };`. Also, your check (`device != NULL`) is useless. It will never be true. And you still need to initialize the Windows Runtime (`winrt::init_apartment();`).

Comment: @IInspectable. It does not matter at this time. He has to understand basics first.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko: It does matter. If you simply turn your asynchronous calls into blocking calls, chances are that you get debug assertions, because you are blocking the GUI thread. That's not helpful if you are trying to learn.

Comment: Its console app. He must anyway block its execution to wait result. Otherwise it exits. co_await does int internally with some message processing (very long storry how it executes it with mutex and threads).

Comment: @MikePetrichenko: Yes, a console application needs to prevent exiting, before the application has performed its intended purpose. The OP is doing that already, by calling `cin.get()`. That blocking call does not raise a debug assertion. Besides, `co_await` does not block. It's a suspension point, returning control back to the caller.

Comment: You are mixing up different things. There are 3 ways to wait on async operation completion: 1. co_await; 2. Event handler; 3. Wait on status in while(). co_await uses event handler internally (by some other way, but you can think about it like: it creates event object, assigns event handler and waits on event). co_await any way blocks execution until operation completed. Also, if your application initializes OLE (for Drag&Drop for example) WinRT will be initialized as SINGLE_THREAD_APARTMENT and co_await and event handler may not work as expected. co_await just saves few code lines.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko: It's not immediately clear, where you believe I mixed up anything. And I still stand by the statement, that `co_await` doesn't block. It's a suspension point that returns control back to the caller. It's also wrong to assume, that `co_await` uses any particular implementation. It executes whatever is implemented by the awaitable object it's used on. All of that is explained in the very first article I linked to. With that clarified, are you suggesting that using `cin.get()` to block application exit were somehow wrong?

Comment: Ok, forget it. I do not think its a good place to discuss our understanding and to measure our knowlages. If you would like to discuss it deeper contact me directly by skype (mike.petrichenko) or offer other place for that.

Comment: I asnwered you by skype but can not post more cause you are offline.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the reading, I understand what's going on now. However, when I try to use `auto const device{ co_await FromBluetoothAddressASync(args.BluetoothAddress()) };`, it gives me error code e0135 and c2039.

Comment: Solved, the function has to "return" IAsyncAction in order to use coroutines.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, thank you for your help.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for your help.

Comment: The return type of a coroutine must be an awaitable. An awaitable is a type on which `await_ready()`, `await_suspend()`, and `await_resume()` can be called. `IAsyncAction` is a predefined type meeting those requirements, but it isn't the only type you can use as the return type of a coroutine.